# Access guice container in Dropwiard application

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard, dropwizard-guice

I want to use dependency inject only in certain part of my code. I am using [HubSpot/dropwizard-guice](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice) to integrate drop-wizard and guice. Is there a way I can access guice object instances programmatically without changing the full project. Basically I would replace initialised objects with guice objects, So that I don't have to change everything at once.

Here is my application file

```java
public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application<HelloWorldConfiguration> {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new HelloWorldApplication().run(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<HelloWorldConfiguration> bootstrap) {

    GuiceBundle<HelloWorldConfiguration> guiceBundle = GuiceBundle.<HelloWorldConfiguration>newBuilder()
      .addModule(new HelloWorldModule())
      .enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
      .setConfigClass(HelloWorldConfiguration.class)
      .build();

    bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "hello-world";
  }

  @Override
  public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration helloWorldConfiguration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can access guice injector without explicitly passing it as a method param all over my project?

Or Is there a way to directly get class instances from guice.

Comment: I would make a singleton that wraps your guiceBundle object and initialize it at startup(or lazy if needed), then just call that wrapper.